# google script internet explorer9 not working

Tags: internet-explorer, google-apps-script, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I developed google script page and tried in IE9, IE10, Google Chrome.

IE10 and Google Chrome worked well, but IE9 didn't support google script code.(just shown 'loading' and no more response)

Am I missing some code for IE9 in google script?

Or IE9 originally doesn't support google script?

Please let me know.

Comment: Please clarify some things: what is a "google script page"? Is it an analytics snippet? Is it a google appengine hosted page? Is it Google Script embedded in a google doc?  Can you give a link to it? Or put your code on jsfiddle.net for testing?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Google script means Google apps script which is developing language like javascript supported by Google[link](http://script.google.com)

Comment: Here is example: [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzTYiaz6ajyE98Nj-59o67ZSWWpmaYVJ6Bi0rZjtmOO84f6iiiU/exec) -> this is sample example written by me(owner)

Comment: If there is anybody who uses IE9, plz try this link [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzTYiaz6ajyE98Nj-59o67ZSWWpmaYVJ6Bi0rZjtmOO84f6iiiU/exec) And answer me whether script page is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your link out on IE9
The default docs mode of the page is Quirks Mode. This causes the following 404 error:
`GET /macros/s/AKfycbzTYiaz6ajyE98Nj-59o67ZSWWpmaYVJ6Bi0rZjtmOO84f6iiiU/gwt/undefined.cache.js`

If I change the Document Mode to IE9 Standards, it works fine.
IE8 Mode works fine, IE7 doesn't.  (Stays on Loading...)

It looks like a bug in Google Script, that is if you aren't doing any specific rendering based on user agent/browser? Update: Issue [#3465](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3465) raised on Google Script issue tracker.

Comment: How can I change the Document Mode o IE9 Standards?

Comment: The page output isn't controlled by you is it? Are you rendering the html out? If you can, see the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975107/force-to-use-internet-explorer-ie9-standards-document-mode
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Nope, I didn't embed gs(google script) code into HTML document. That link that I wrote above is pure script code.

Comment: Do I have to embed into HTML?

Comment: Can't you show us a script example that has the same issue? You don't have to use the actual code you use, just a cut down example.

Comment: Here is google script sample code
 function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();   
   var anchor = app.createAnchor("a link", "http://www.google.com");
   app.add(anchor);
   return app;
 }

Comment: Thanks Jehyun, this looks like a bug in Google Script that you can't do much about. I've raised an issue on their issue tracker for Script here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3465  You can star the issue there to follow it.

Comment: Thank you very much David!
I will check that page.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.setStandardsMode(true)` to your app like so:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setStandardsMode(true);
```

That loaded for me in IE9.

Comment: Worked for me as far as I can remember

Answer (score 0):

Here is Google script sample code .
Google script is different from javascript

Google script code should be running under Google script environment(http://script.google.com)

```
function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   var anchor = app.createAnchor("a link", "http://www.google.com");
   app.add(anchor);
   return app;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Running an application in IE9 does not necessarily mean you are running IE9 standards mode. IE9 has many modes that can be defined in the page head tag (see the “Document Mode” section below). You can overwrite the page mode manually by selecting F12, where you can set both browser mode and document mode.

GWT IE permutations work best with each version of “standards” mode. Mixing modes, say browser mode = 7 and document mode = 9, is not recommended and the behavior is undefined. To keep it simple, try to keep browser modes and document modes the same. If you must use mixed mode, be aware that you may run into issues that are still not supported. The exception is if you are emulating an older browser when you still do not support the new version, for instance, you emulate IE7 (EmulateIE7) on IE9.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9.html