# Internet Explorer retro-compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, sharepoint, compatibility

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and SharePoint 2010.

I created a simple HTML page whit CSS, JavaScript and jQuery. I hosted my page in a SharePoint's page. I added a simple WebPart (Page Viewer) that link to my HTML page.

If I open my page with IE11, on my local machine, is rendered correctly; it doesn't work on SharePoint'page.

I see the property "document mode" of page on my local machine is "10" while in SharePoint 2010 has  "8".

What is "document mode" property? How can I resolve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your doctype and meta tags ..in other words, your html header :)

Comment: Hi. This is my header code:<code><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/mycss.css" />
 ...
    <!-- JavaScript Link -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./JavaScript/myjavascript.js"></script>
 ...</code>

Comment: Next time, update your question instead as comments might get deleted... try adding this meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> `

Comment: I also think you should start using this doctype, which also might solve (or is needed to solve) your problem: `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is correct. After your response I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975107/force-to-use-internet-explorer-ie9-standards-document-mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference if <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> exists or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem adding this code on html's head element:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

I found solutions there: [Forcing Internet Explorer 9 to use standards document mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975107/force-to-use-internet-explorer-ie9-standards-document-mode)