# ReportViewer 11 with IE 11: report height exceeds limits

Tags: asp.net, css, reportviewer

We are using Microsoft ReportViewer 11 to display our business reports. 
On our aspx page, we just include it as:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" Width="830px" Height="800px" />
```

Everything went fine until our clients upgraded from IE 10 to IE 11.
In IE 10, reports were correctly displayed within the defined size, showing scrollbars,
when the report exceeds the limits. The same goes for Firefox or other browsers. 
In IE 11 instead, the report is shown in full length, meaning, that the report exceeds the 
lower border, without showing scroll bars. Same happens, when I activate the compatibility mode in IE 11.

PS: We have all service packs and newest reportviewer 2012 runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use compatibility mode as it doesn't change how the page is displayed. Instead, set the document mode. See [How to set doc mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184243/how-to-set-ie-document-mode)

Comment: For documentation purpose. I added as suggested:
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
.repViewer{overflow-y:auto !important;}
```

```html
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server"  Height="400px" CssClass="repViewer">
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the report view control in a DIV and set it's height to 800px and set overflow to auto.  This way you do not have to modify the default document mode.

Comment: Explicitly writing out this HTML yourself is helpful.  It also helps reduces the chances of people misinterpreting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was parent element height is lesser than the child element height even you are specified the overflow-y:auto in your parent css it will not taken in IE-11.0.40 version.

It is the problem IE new update -KB4012204

we have to use the following code in script, problem will be solved

i am just assigning the parent element height to child element to solve the issue

```
    var div = document.getElementById('ctl00_body_rvReport_ctl10');
if (typeof (div) != 'undefined' && div != null) div.style.height =div.parentElement.clientHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as described with ReportViewer v10.
It only appears on IE11.  Other browsers just work fine.

I finally fix it by adding a section of codes in my report aspx file.

```
<style type="text/css">   
  div[id='yourreportid']
  { 
   height: 1px;   
  }
</style>
```

I find that the value of height doesn't matter. Put in any value in px unit will work. Put in height: 100%; DOES NOT work.