# Specify IE document mode in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("https://foo.example.com/login")
```

How can I force this new instance of IE to be in document mode Edge or 10?

By default it loads this site in Document mode 5 and sometimes 7.

Comment: How do you find the document mode from PowerShell?

Comment: Apparently you first get `$ie.document` then you should query its `documentMode` and `compatMode`. But, querying `$ie.document` from Powershell the` documentMode` property is not exposed. Getting `compatMode` is possible, but setting isn't. So I think this is not possible from Powershell. (Probably developer tools are mode authorized in terms of COM objects to get more properties)

Comment: @JanChrbolka I notice it by seeing how messed up the page renders. F12 dev tools then shows that the mode is IE 7.

Comment: @p.campbell , I see..., I agree with Vesper in that the client side settings and properties are not exposed on the COM object in PowerShell. Also, 99% of all references to IE document mode suggest that this is done on the server side. [How to set IE document mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184243/how-to-set-ie-document-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you first get `$ie.document` then you should query its `documentMode` and `compatMode`. But, querying `$ie.document` from Powershell the`documentMode` property is not exposed. Getting `compatMode` is possible, but setting isn't. So I think this is not possible from Powershell. (Probably developer tools are mode authorized in terms of COM objects to get more properties)